# the meaning of cmake set (CMAKE_TARGET_DEFINITIONS

Tags: cmake

I read a CMake file, name is: `depndinfo.cmake`.

I can't understand what is the meaning of SET command:

```
SET(CMAKE_TARGET_DEFINITIONS
  "DEM_DONT_PROVIDE_LEGACY_SYMBOLIC_NAMES"
  "MAIN_SW_VERSION_MAJOR=16"
  "MAIN_SW_PART_NUMBER_COMBINED=0x44,0x32,0x31,0x38,0x34,0x35,0x37,0x31,0x20,0x20"
)
```

Is this command like a multiple definitions macros?

Comment: The command creates variable `CMAKE_TARGET_DEFINITIONS` which value is a *list* of 3 strings: `DEM_DONT_PROVIDE_LEGACY_SYMBOLIC_NAMES`, `MAIN_SW_VERSION_MAJOR=16` and `MAIN_SW_PART_NUMBER_COMBINED=...`. Actual meaning of this variable is up to the script itself.

Answer (score 1):

See [The Architecture of Open Source Applications: CMake](http://www.aosabook.org/en/cmake.html):

> `DependInfo.cmake` is used to keep the dependency information up-to-date and contains information about what files are part of the project and what languages they are in.

The file is generated by CMake's makefile generators **for internal use** for each target under:

```
<binary output dir>/CMakeFiles/<target name>.dir/DependInfo.cmake
```

The variable `CMAKE_TARGET_DEFINITIONS` in your example does list the pre-processor definitions for the target in question.